# Tomcat jar files in sub dirs of lib are automatically moved into lib folder on deployment?

Tags: java, tomcat, myeclipse

Hi I have some jar files placed in some subdir of the lib folder in my project say `MyProject/lib/A/some.jar`. When I deploy my project in tomcat the jar files automatically move inside the lib folder of the tomcat from `/lib/A` to `/lib`. in the webapps folder. What could be the reason for such behaviour?

P.S I am using `MyEclipse` for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you have entries in the deployment assembly which causes this. Select the project, right click and select Properties then go to the MyEclipse->Deployment Assembly page. Check the entries and remove or edit the offending entries. If you don't have a Deployment Assembly page then you may be using quite an old release of MyEclipse, in which case, I can't think what the problem might be.